# Nhibernate query<T> / queryover<T> orderby a subquery

Tags: nhibernate, sql-order-by, subquery, queryover

I am having issues getting Nhibernate 3.3.2.4000 to generate the correct subquery used in the orderby clause as displayed below:

```
select *
from dbo.Person p inner join dbo.Task t on p.Task_FK = p.TaskId    
order by (select p.CustomerNumber where p.IsMain=1) desc
```

We have two entities: `Task` and `Person`

One task can have N persons related to it. I.e Task has an IList property.

How can I make Nhibernate generate the correct subquery ? I have gotten as far as something like this with the Query API:

```
query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Persons.Single(t => t.CustomerNumber));
```

but I am unsure how I can correctly generate the where clause as displayed in the original sql query. Is this perhaps easier done using the queryover api somehow?

Any advice or guidance is most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
Task task = null
Person person = null;
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<Task>()
    .Where(t => t.Id == task.Id)
    .JoinQueryOver(t => t.Persons, () => person)
    .Where(p => p.IsMain)
    .Select(() => person.CustomerNumber);

var query = session.QueryOver(() => task)
    .OrderBy(Projections.SubQuery(subquery))
    .FetchMany(x => x.Persons)

return query.List();
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Firo. The select clause in the subquery gives the error cannot resolve method select(lamda expression). Any clues?

Comment: what if you write `.Select(_ => person.CustomerNumber)`?